# Why changed my solona after failed transaction to wraped solona?

Tags: transactions, wallet, deposit

I was deposit solona to my phantom Wallet after i try buying some coin but always say : fail .. later i withdraw to my Bybit Wallet but i dont know why swaped to wraped solona but i not swap that! And the Bybit cant help me because there not listed the wraped solona So i lose my money..? [image]

https://solscan.io/tx/629eLxehD2TpsmmGnJ54msALP42MpXLW5o7VQPsbQjXUy57ruRvaaazkfTMgeZAyzgR8r5u4Mbm7tusbYNKnfHqh

Comment: You can unwrap the wrapped SOL in phantom wallet. click on it and click on the dots in the upper right-hand corner. and click unwrap

Comment: I dont saw how wraped solona too late i see when already withdraw to Bybit Wallet but in Bybit dont have wraped SoL

Comment: unwrap the wrapped SOL in your phantom wallet